# AWS image upload with Python/Django is not working

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, file-upload, django-views

I am a beginner using Python/Django. few months ago I deployed an app that has an image upload feature which is connected with AWS S3 buckets. when I run the server locally on my machine, the app works fine.
However I deployed the app to Heroku and the image upload stopped working, no errors in the console, and the image itself is not even uploaded to the AWS bucket.

**This is my views for uploading the images:**

```
def add_photo(request, team_id):
    photo_file = request.FILES.get('photo-file', None)
    if photo_file:
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        key = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6] + photo_file.name[photo_file.name.rfind('.'):]

        try:
            s3.upload_fileobj(photo_file, BUCKET, key)
            url = f"{S3_BASE_URL}{BUCKET}/{key}"
            photo = Photo(url=url, team_id = team_id)
            photo.save()

        except Exception as e :
            print('An error occured uploading files to s3')
            print(e)
    return redirect('teams_detail', team_id = team_id)
```

**this is the template for upload :**

```
 {% for photo in team.photo_set.all %}

        <img src="{{photo.url}}" alt="{{photo.url}}" class="responsive-img card-panel">
        {% empty %}
            <div class="card-panel teal-text center-align">No Photos Uploaded</div>
        {% endfor %}
        <form class="card-panel" action="{% url 'add_photo' team.id %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="file" name="photo-file">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Upload Photo">
        </form>
```

Like I said this is an app that I created a few months ago. so appreciate if you can point out to me what I am getting wrong or if i missed an important detail to be shared as well

[image: Heroku Logs]

Comment: What is the error that you get? Where is the value of `BUCKET` coming from?

Comment: Have you checked the security on the S3 bucket (i.e., if you can save when app running locally but not when running on Heroku have you set up any security groups allowing your local IP)?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I am not getting any error , when the app is running locally, I upload any picture I want and I see it in the AWS console. However the deployed version on Heroku does not allow me to upload anything. just an empty chrome console and the AWS console does not show anything, I will add a screenshot of the Heroku logs, may be it will be helpful, Check the main post

Comment: @geektechstuffI am not sure how to do that, can you provide documentation for that?

Comment: "_An error occured uploading files to S3_" is that not an error?... Check that you have specified the `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` env vars correctly.

Comment: will do, but wouldn't the upload now work as well on local servers if there was a problem with AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY AND AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID.
I will double check it once I get back home

Comment: apologies for the belated response. so I checked the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY AND AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
I have the AND AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
 inside the app(the app works locally just fine) but I can't confirm where to find the
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY on AWS console. I only have in inside the app 
if you don't mind, what do you think happened in the deployment that messed the image uploading, should I move that file into (may be) the build folder. I am a total beginner and using AWS for the first time

Comment: It actually worked, you were right.I had the wrong AWS_SECRET_KEY However I don't understand how come it worked locally but not when deployed !!